# 1D Gaussian filter horizontally and vertically

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, gaussian

I am trying to generate Gaussian filter that can be applied on the images, but I want to apply it 1D twice: horizontally and vertically. In addition, I want to apply it to each planes separately.

That mean I want to design 1D Gaussian filter to apply it horizontally in Red, Green, Blue component, then I have the same 1D Gaussian filter to apply it vertically in Red, Green, Blue component.

And I think this operation should equal applying 2D Gaussian filter on the original color image.

I am new in Matlab and in image processing filter.

Comment: paisanco I see this post ... it does not help me .... because I want to use fspecial ,imfilter , conv functions in matlab

Comment: Fair enough but if you have the image processing toolbox I'm not sure what the question is, was there some aspect not covered in the Matlab docs for those functions?

Comment: I am not familiar with image processing toolbox in Matlab ... also I am still new in these filters .... my questions is how can I apply the gaussian filter horizontally in the image for example ( 1D not 2D)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A convolution with 2D Gaussian can be performed with two 1D Gaussians as:

```
G(x,y)*I=G(x)*(G(y)*I);
```

You can do this in MATLAB as follows:

```
img=im2double(imread('cameraman.tif'));

yourFilterSize=[3 5] %3 rows, 5 columns, can be anything

%two 1D Gaussians
g_x=fspecial('gaussian',[1 yourFilterSize(2)]);
g_y=fspecial('gaussian',[yourFilterSize(1) 1]);

%applying 1D gaussian in X-direction to the original image
img_X=imfilter(img,g_x);

%applying 1D gaussian in Y-direction to img_X
img_XY=imfilter(img_X,g_y);  %DONE

%verifying that the result is correct
g_xy=fspecial('gaussian',yourFilterSize);
img_XY2D=imfilter(img,g_xy);
max(max(abs(img_XY-img_XY2D)))  %this should be very small, 
                                %of the order of machine precision
                                %for the result to be correct
```

Additional reading:

1. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25218173/1586200) answer on Stackoverflow.com  which shows you how to determine whether a given kernel is separable. For example, Gaussian is separable, while the disk kernel is not.
2. [Original article](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2006/10/04/separable-convolution/) for above mentioned issue.

---

Why would you prefer two 1D convolutions instead of one 2D convolution (also given in the link 2 mentioned above):

Suppose you have an image of size `MxN` and a filter of size `PxQ` then for a 2D convolution, you need `~ M*P*N*Q` multiplications and additions. For two 1D filters (of size `P` and `Q`), you only need `~ MNP+MNQ = MN(P+Q)` operations. Therefore, you get a speedup of the order of `PQ/(P+Q)`.

Comment: Thanks Parag S. Chandakkar for your help ... I have question, why you select [ 3 3] ? .... how can determine the size here?

Comment: That's just an example. Please check the updated answer. If you find the answer helpful, please accept it by clicking the check mark on the left hand side.